# Can't interact with SQL Server cli inside docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker

I just installed `mssql` from the [official](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) container

But when I try to access it's `cli` using this command

```
docker exec -it <container_id|container_name> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P <your_password>
```

it opens a `cli` but it doesn't do anything at all like this

[image]

Comment: Not sure on this, so just a comment, but the `1>`, `2>`, `3>`, etc to me indicates lines of the same script that's not finished yet... it hasn't run anything.

Comment: but i didn't write anything yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)

> These statements are sent to SQL Server after you type the GO command and press ENTER

So, type `GO` and press the enter key.